# Workaround for federated ID changing depending on domain name?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, openid, google-openid

I have a webapp on google app engine that checks to see if a user is logged in (through the federated id) with the following code.  I just changed domain names and now for some reason it isn't recognizing any of my current users.  This is because the openID changes depending on the domain name which I found through a little testing.  Is there any workaround or way to let these users log in?

```
user = users.get_current_user()
currentregistereduser = None
try:
    user_db_qry = User.query(User.theid == user.federated_identity())
    user_db_list = user_db_qry.fetch(1)
    currentregistereduser = user_db_list[0]

    # I go on here to do all of the stuff for a logged in user

#if the user does not exist yet
except IndexError:
    logging.error("indexerror" + str(User.theid) + " and " + str(user.federated_identity()))
    user_db = User(
        name=user.nickname(),
        email=user.email(),
        theid=user.federated_identity(),
        visits = 0,
        medals = 0,
        prestige = 1,
        )
    user_db.put()
    #they go on to create their profile data here
    self.redirect("/profile")
```

Comment: Do you (or your users) still have access to the other domain?

Comment: yes I still own it and right now it is redirecting page for page to the new URL but it wouldn't be too hard to even put the whole site back.  why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a similar problem to the one faced by StackExchange when it implemented OpenID. You can see how they dealt with it here:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/openid-one-year-later/

From that page:

So our cross-site user account matching now works this way:

1. Match by GUID. This is something we generate and assign during account association, so it’s a perfect fingerprint.
2. match by OpenID URL. This works for the vast majority of OpenID providers.
3. match by OpenID provided email address … if you are on our trust whitelist. This works for those rare OpenID providers (currently, only Google GMail) who generate domain-specific identifiers.

You could also try using a OpenID Library. Several are listed here:
http://openid.net/developers/libraries/

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks so much for the link, a very clear explanation and gives me a few good options for ways to fix the problem.  Luckily I was requiring emails for all users with Google so that helps!

Comment: do you have any idea if it is the same for OAuth users with Google?